# How to add a new image size and apply it to posts only?

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails, images

I'd like to create a new image size and write another function that basically says that if I'm applying this new image to any posts to use this new image size.

`function add_image_size( 'story_thumb', 640, 640, array( 'center', 'center' ) );`

Is the function I have for the new image size. I want it to be 640x640 and crop in the dead center horizontally and vertically.

Now, if I can make this apply only to posts that be great, but I'm not sure how to write this conditional statement. I'm also wondering if it's possible to take it a step further to target posts tagged with a specific parent category.

I feel like this could be modified to make this work:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    the_post_thumbnail( 'story_thumb' ); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this if you want it to apply to just single posts with post-type as post:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    if ( is_singular('post') ) {
        the_post_thumbnail( 'story_thumb' );
    } else {
        the_post_thumbnail( );
    }
}
```

or this if you want to check if the post is in a particular category.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    if ( is_singular('post') && in_category( 'category_slug' ) ) {
        the_post_thumbnail( 'story_thumb' );
    } else {
        the_post_thumbnail( );
    }
}
```

Where you replace ***category_slug*** with your category's slug or an array of category slugs.

To use this in a function, you can define the custom function in your functions.php file as so

```
if ( !function_exists('my_custom_post_thumbnail') ) {
    function my_custom_post_thumbnail() {
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            if ( is_singular('post') ) {
                the_post_thumbnail( 'story_thumb' );
            } else {
            the_post_thumbnail( );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then replace `the_post_thumbnail` in your theme with **`my_custom_post_thumbnail`**

Comment: can this be used in a function?

Comment: @DarrenBachan I've included a custom function wrapper for the code

Comment: Do I need an add action or anything with this function?

Comment: this function kills the page, 500 error.

Comment: What error are you getting in your error log

Comment: The error ended up being on my end. This worked. Thanks!